# JUnit NoSuchMethodError: CompilationResult.getErrors() with Play tests

Tags: junit, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to run Play 1.2.3 tests from command line and get this error:

```
[junit] Testcase: initializationError(com.package.MyTest):  Caused an ERROR
[junit] org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getErrors()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
[junit] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getErrors()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
```

I tried adding several Eclipse and Jasper jars but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding [gwt-dev-2.1.1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgwtdev211jar.htm) to classpath.